# Converting HEX to DEC is out of range by using `mawk`

Tags: shell, awk

When the hex number is relative small, I can use `echo 0xFF| mawk '{ printf "%d\n", $1}'` to convert hex to dec.

When then hex number is huge, mawk does not work any more, say  `echo 0x8110D248 | mawk '{ printf "%d\n", $1}'` outputs `2147483647`(which is equivalent to 0x7FFFFFFF).

Comment: It seems there is an issue with negative numbers. `0x8FFFFFFF` is negative ... so `printf` seems to do an interesting conversion there. The issue does not exist with gnu awk using the `-n` flag (`--non-decimal-data`)

Comment: @kvantour
 But `xargs printf` is **very very slow** when processing a lot of numbers.

Comment: What do you really want to do?

Comment: `2147483647` is the largest signed 32-bit number. You need to add the `'l'` modifier, e.g. `printf "%ld\n", $1` to handle conversion for numbers larger than 32-bit.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Does not work indeed.You can try `echo 0x8110D248 | mawk '{ printf "%u(%x)\n", $1, $1}'` and verify.

Comment: @kvantour fyi `-n`/`--non-decimal-data` is deprecated in favor of `strtonum()`, see "CAUTION" at https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Nondecimal-Data.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a duplicate of https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/684925/133219.

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is converting Hex to Decimal, I wonder why you are using `mawk`. Can't you do something like

```
 echo 'ibase=16;8110D248' |bc
```

(this outputs `2165363272`).

Answer (score 0):

`bash` can also do this (and zsh and pdksh):

```
echo $(( 0x8110D248 ))
```

Output:

```
2165363272
```